# import a file from different folder in python

Tags: python, import

I am trying to import a `.py` from a different folder in my project but got the `Module not found error`. Please help.

this is my project tree.

```
PROJECT_name
+trnsvr
|
\--trn_db.py

+websvr
|
\--instance
   |
   --config.py
\--app
   |
   --__init__.py
```

in `trn_db.py`
I did
`import websvr.instance.config as conf`

but got the `ModuleNotFoundError` as follow.

`ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'websvr'`

how do I resolve this?  thank you

Comment: try `import websvr.instance.config as conf.py`

Comment: I tried and it throws me a Syntax Error :(

Answer (score 0):

Try copying this into `trn_db.py`.
I got this from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4383571/importing-files-from-different-folder).

```
import sys
sys.path.insert(1, '../websvr/instance/')
import config as conf
```

Comment: thank you but it did not worked for me : ( Driving me crazy lol

Answer (score 0):

Try to specify the file path... `c:/MicrosoftVSCode/randomthings1.py`. When not right next to it (in the same folder), python has sometimes problems accessing files. Also, make sure antimalware software isn't blocking python's access. <- My case

Comment: where do I specify the file path?

Comment: Right before the file name, e.g. `../websvr/instance/config.py`